# Data not properly passed to php server

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I have an app that reads in Json data from phpmyadmin thru a php script and displayed in a list activity.  Once a store name is clicked, +1 is added to the vote count for that store and is supposed to be sent back to the php server to store the new vote count in phpmyadmin. After the selection, I check the db vote count value and it is not updated. Although I get HTTP/1.1 200 ok in logcat, I don't think the data is being passed or taken in correctly.  Can someone help, I'm stuck and have no direction.

Android code:

```
public void writeJSON() {
    String convertedID;
    String convertedVote;

    //convert int to string value to passed
    convertedID = new Integer(selectedID).toString();
    convertedVote = new Integer(selectedVote).toString();

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/kcstores.php");

    try {

       //writes the output to be stored in creolefashions.com/test2.php
       ArrayList <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>(2);
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("storeUpdate", "update"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("storeID", convertedID));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("storeVote", convertedVote));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        Log.i("writeJSON", response.getStatusLine().toString());

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString()); 
        } 
}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("king_cake_stores")or die (mysql_error());

    $query = "SELECT * FROM storeInfo";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $getUpdate = "noupdate";

    if (isset($_POST['storeUpdate'])) {
      echo "receiving data from app";
      $getUpdate = $_POST['storeUpdate'];
      $getStoreID = $_POST['storeID'];
      $getStoreVote = $_POST['storeVote'];
    }

    // If command == getStoreID, it updates the table storeVote value
    // with the android storeVote value based upon correct storeID 
    if ($getUpdate == "update") {
       mysql_select_db("UPDATE storeInfo SET storeVote = $getStoreVote
          WHERE storeID == $getStoreID");
    } else {
    // stores the data in an array to be sent to android application
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $output[]=$line;
        print(json_encode($output));
    }
     mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: you have `==` instead of `=` in your update query, also sql injection

Comment: I have it there because where the when the storeId == getStoreId, it means it's the same record, therefore proceed with the update.

Comment: [Back to school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) `=` Equal

Comment: Why is it that the "=" alone in other instances assigns values to the right var to the left.  Is it different when using the update statment?

Comment: Thanks Lawrence!  Your answer combined with Dan's finally got my program to working!  I really appreciate it

Comment: @skip In MySQL := is a variable assignment. PHP uses "=", but this wasn't in the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start debugging from the server end and start working your way backwards.

First, start logging the response text from your HttpResponse.

Echo the mysql query text in your php file, and make sure it looks the way you're expecting it to.

If it looks correct, check your database structure.

If not, try doing a `var_dump($_POST)`, and check to see if your parameters are being sent correctly.

If you run through these steps, you should have a better idea of where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I finally got it working.  I'll employ this on my next issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the whole problem, but:

```
mysql_select_db("UPDATE storeInfo SET storeVote = $getStoreVote
      WHERE storeID == $getStoreID");
```

That should be `mysql_query`.

Comment: Thanks Dan!  Your answer combined with Lawrence's finally got my program to working!  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this, using PDO:

```
<?php 
//Db Connection Class
Class db{
    private static $instance = NULL;
    private function __construct() {}

    public static function getInstance($DBUSER,$DBPASS) {
        if (!self::$instance){
            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=king_cake_stores", $DBUSER, $DBPASS);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }catch (Exception $e){
                die('Cannot connect to mySQL server.');
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    private function __clone(){}
}

//Connect to PDO
$db = db::getInstance('username','password');

//Inser Update
if (isset($_POST['storeUpdate'])) {

    try {
        /*** UPDATE data ***/
        $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE storeInfo
                               SET storeVote = :storeVote
                               WHERE storeID = :storeID");

        $query->bindParam(':storeVote', $_POST['storeVote'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':storeID',   $_POST['storeID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
        $query->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

//Output Current
}else{
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM storeInfo')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
/*** close the database connection ***/
$db = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `or die` after every PHP command. Also use try catch blocks in Android
This will reduce errors in the code.